# multiple statements after if statement

Tags: awk

I have an awk line to calculate an average that works fine but when I put it into an if statement, I get a syntax error referring to the part with "END". I want to calculate the average only if certain conditions are fulfilled.

Line for calculating average that works:

`awk '{ sum += $2; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }' input.txt`

Line for calculating average after if statement which doesn't work:

`awk '{if ( $1 > 5 ) { {sum += $2; n++} END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }}}' input.txt`

I would like to know where the error is, changing the type and number of brackets did not help.

Comment: Why do you think you can put a pattern inside a block?

Comment: I thought it works as if I'm just executing them together.

Comment: You should probably remove your "bash" tag, this is a pure `awk` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
awk '$1>5 {sum+=$2; n++}
     END  {if(n) print sum/n}' file
```